scaling a pattern to fill a selection in Photoshop
I’d like to create a Photoshop action to automatically fill a selection with another image and scale the image to fit to cover the selection.
For example, I’d like the action to fill a circle with the image below.
I tried defining a pattern, but I wasn’t able to find a script that would either create a single instance of the pattern or scale the pattern down to cover the selection.
Is there a pattern script that will scale a pattern to fit to cover a selection?
Or will another Photoshop tool do this?

Here's what the fill would look like in this example:


Thanks.  I loaded a screenshot of the circle filled with the image and scaled to cover.

If you do not want a pattern tile repeat, then a pattern is the completely wrong direction. The repeat is the entire point of any pattern.

Is the example you are showing simplified or do your actual images look like this? I'm just wondering why you would first spend time on making a circular mask and then afterwards make a circular image fit. Why not just add the circular image to begin with to remove one step? I feel like we aren't getting the full story here.

The circle is a simple example.  The action uses Select Color Range to make a selection.  I'd like to fill this selection with the image from the other layer and scale it to cover the selection.  The action then uses the result as a layer mask.
